# Converting LINQ Result to String VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a module that is correctly pulling a Linq query and writing it to a text file. I just need to know how to convert this to the actual string value. Thanks.

```
 Imports System.IO

 Module CheckExists

Public objStreamWriter As StreamWriter

Public Function SimpleQ4()

    Dim dc As New DatabaseDataContext

    Dim q = _
        From a In dc.GetTable(Of tblDealer)() _
        Where a.chvDealerName = "Something" _
        Select a

    Return q.ToString

    objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("path.txt")

    objStreamWriter.WriteLine(q)

End Function

 End Module
```

This is returning in myt text file

```
 SELECT [t0].[iD], etc....
```

Comment: I think this is because you haven't actually 'executed' your query yet, due to LINQ's deferred execution. Try Select a.FirstOrDefault() in your query

Comment: its saying that FirstOrDefault isnt a member of my table

Comment: ok, now my textfile is blank and the item does exist in the table

Comment: I'm not really familiar with VB, but does your function exit on the Return statement? If so, it means the streamwriter code will never be run.  can you debug the code in Visual Studio so you can see what the value of 'q' is.

Comment: it will definitely never run!

Comment: You're calling a `Return` before you're finished with your Function. Everything after the `Return` is not likely to be called and confuse the compiler, if anything.

Comment: Ok it looks like each column in the database is becoming ConsoleApplication1.tblDealer)(q)).Items(0)._chvDealerName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works

```
  Public Sub textFile()

    Dim ddc As New DatabaseDataContext

    Dim q = _
    (From a In ddc.GetTable(Of Table)() _
            Where a.Name = "Something" _
            Select a.Name).ToList

    For Each item In q
        objStreamWriter.WriteLine(item)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function SimpleQ4()
    Dim dc As New DatabaseDataContext
    Dim q = _
        From a In dc.GetTable(Of tblDealer)() _
        Where a.chvDealerName = "Something" _
        Select New With
        {
            myFirstColumn = a.columnName,
            mySecondColumn = a.anotherColumnName,
            ...
        }

    objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter("path.txt")
    objStreamWriter.WriteLine(q)
End Function
```

The LINQ query will not have data until the streamwriter actually starts writing data due to LINQs deferred execution.

Inside the curly braces you are creating an anonymous type. Every column you want a property for would be on the left side of the equal sign. If you don't want to create and map all of the columns use this instead:

```
        From a In dc.GetTable(Of tblDealer)() _
        Where a.chvDealerName = "Something" _
        Select a
```

If you need to see the contents of the query, add `q.ToList()` on the line before creating the streamwriter.